How to reroute 5 cables from street pole into attic?
I currently have 5 cables coming from a pole across the street. They have them attached to the eave of the house and that don't seem correct and the eave is tilting away from the house. One of the cables has pulled out the anchor and no longer has any stress relief.
I'd like to add something stronger that they can all connect to and attach it under the eave.
I'd also like to bring the cables into the attic.
Not sure if there is an anchor that would accommodate them all. The what kind of opening could I use to bring them all into the attic?


are those power or data cabels

If they are for cable/internet, the cables outside might belong to the company/their responsibility.  If power cables, then do not even think of touching them.  Same goes if mixed.

They are low voltage data cables.

Check with your ISP/Cable/phone company what you can do.  Some will do the work for you.  This is assuming they come from the pole on the street and not house to shed/garage.

You have two different questions:  how to add something to attach the cables to the house (because what has been doing that is pulling away from the house--this is a carpentry question); how to get them inside.  I could answer the second question if you make a separate question for it.  It would help if you'd add pictures showing the cables travel from where they hit the house to where they enter the house now.  There are almost certainly two external boxes before the wires enter the house.  You don't want to bring the wires inside before the boxes.  I can't answer how to fix the carpentry.

The thought was to add a sturdy hook under the eave for all cables strain relief, that is not pulling the facia boards apart. Then bring all the cables into the attic. What do you use when you have 4 or 5 cables that need to go through an external wall?
The next step would be to mount the boxes (if still needed) in the attic or run the cables down to the utility room and mount the boxes there and then onto the wall jacks.
Rather than all the cables going down the front of the house the then across the side to boxes under the carport on the side of the house and then into the house.
